# How to auto-size a image to fit div when div width is in vmin

Tags: html, css

`I am trying to run the following code but my image is always to large for my div so it comes partially

```
.display-box
 {
 width:80vmin;
 padding:50px 40px;
 background-image: url("paper.gif");
 background-size: cover; 
 position: absolute;
 width: 80vmin;
 height:80vmin;
 padding:50px 40px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```

I tried using background-size: cover and background-size: contain along with no-repeat center center fixed;
but it did not work.`

Comment: You need to choose: the image can either fully cover the div but possibly get clipped, which is what `background-size: cover` does, or it can fully fit in the div but possibly not fill the full width/height of the div, which is what `background-size: contain` does. The only way to fully fill the div and not clip the image is if the image and the div are the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to maintain the aspect ratio then you can use

`background-size: 100% 100%;`